# sort multidimension array by its keys and then by its value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort two dimension array but its keys and its values.
Array is like this

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Transport] => imagem3.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Transport] => imagem2.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Transport] => imagem1.png
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [First] => dscn2439.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [First] => dscn2454.jpg
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [First] => 06052010282.jpg
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [First] => dscn2357.jpg
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 120140220_191807.jpg
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Manufacture] => 20140220_191429.jpg
        )
)
```

I have sorted array of array by its keys but what I want to do is I want to array like this

```
<?php Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem1.png
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem2.png
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem3.png
    )

[3] => Array
    (
       [First] => dscn2357.jpg
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [First] => dscn2439.jpg
    )

[5] => Array
    (
         [First] => dscn2454.jpg
    )

[6] => Array
    (
       [First] => 06052010282.jpg
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Manufacture] => 120140220_191807.jpg
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [Manufacture] => 20140220_191429.jpg
    )
 )
 ?>
```

I have sorted by its keys I am not able to sort by value please help what I have to do

```
function getListPortfolio($params){

        $dir ='./images/portfolio/';
        // Open a directory, and read its contents
        $folderArray=array();
        $fileArray=array();
        $extArray=array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif');
        if (is_dir($dir)){
          if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($subdir = readdir($dh)) !== false){             
                if(is_dir($dir.$subdir)){
                    if(!($subdir=='.' || $subdir=='..')){
                         $folderArray[]=$subdir;
                    }
                }
            }

            arsort($folderArray);
            foreach($folderArray as $key=>$value){
                if($dhSub = opendir($dir.$value)){
                     while (($files = readdir($dhSub)) !== false){
                        $fileExists=$dir.$value.'/'.$files;
                        if(exif_imagetype($fileExists)){
                            if(is_file($fileExists)){
                                $fileArray[][$value]=$files;                                        
                            }
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
          }
        }
        return $fileArray;
    }
```

I want dir in key and files in value.

Solve:

```
function getListPortfolio($params){

        $dir ='./images/portfolio/';
        // Open a directory, and read its contents
        $folderArray=array();
        $fileArray=array();
        $data=array();
        $extArray=array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif');
        if (is_dir($dir)){
          if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($subdir = readdir($dh)) !== false){             
                if(is_dir($dir.$subdir)){
                    if(!($subdir=='.' || $subdir=='..')){
                         $folderArray[]=$subdir;
                    }
                }
            }

            arsort($folderArray);
            foreach($folderArray as $key=>$value){
                if($dhSub = opendir($dir.$value)){
                     while (($files = readdir($dhSub)) !== false){
                        $fileExists=$dir.$value.'/'.$files;
                        if(exif_imagetype($fileExists)){
                            if(is_file($fileExists)){
                                $fileArray[]=$files;                                        
                            }
                        }
                     }
                     asort($fileArray);
                     foreach($fileArray as $index=>$filename){
                         $data[][$value]=$filename;
                     }

                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
          }
        }
        return $fileArray;
    }
```

Array will look like this and i want to sort array [transport]=>**imagem2.jpg** ' value not [0] this index.

```
Array
( [0] => Array ( [Transport] => imagem1.png )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem2.png
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem3.png
    )

[3] => Array
    (
       [First] => dscn2357.jpg
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [First] => dscn2439.jpg
    )

[5] => Array
    (
         [First] => dscn2454.jpg
    )
)
```

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: i have a created a function which is getting data from a dir and its files so i want to sort by first folder then by its file code is here:-

Comment: we'd like to see what's the function's code :)

Comment: above is my code and i want to array as i have posted but main problem is coming in sorting folder's files and index them as i have mention

Comment: @sujit is there any issue if i do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to sort your array by value. What don't you use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, 'cmp');

print_r($arr);
```

$arr being the array you want to sort.

Comment: i am not geting this can you please explain??

Comment: What do you get then ?

Comment: this is not sorting value if we pass array into this..i have given above array

Comment: can you edit your post and write the array you want to try so I can try it ?

Comment: i have edited my question please check...i want to sort by imagem2.jpeg value so after sorting it will look like:-

`[0] => Array ( [Transport] => imagem3.png )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem2.png
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Transport] => imagem1.png
    )`

Comment: please help i am stuck now. i cannot change my array strucure. i have tried several things but still

Comment: OK can you edit your post and write the ARRAY I can copy and paste BUT NOT THE output of print_r don't show me what it looks like, just write the ARRAY you got in PHP file. Then tell me what you exactly want. Please Be precise since it is hard to understant you. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

call a sorting function and store the return sorted array in a variable **$sorted_array**

```
$sorted_array = sortArray($result, $p_sort_field );
```

Sorting function :

```
<?php

function sortArray($arrData, $p_sort_field, $p_sort_type = false )
{
 if(!empty($arrData))
 {
  foreach($arrData as $data)
  {
   $newData [] = $data;
  }
  for($i=0; $i<count($newData); $i++)
  {                       
    $ar_sort_field[$i]=$newData[$i][$p_sort_field];
  }
  array_multisort($ar_sort_field, ($p_sort_type ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC), $newData);   
  return $newData;
 }
}

?>
```

In **$result** pass your actual array and in **$p_sort_field** pass the field name you want to sort.

Comment: there is no specfic field for sorting as i have already mentioned above